# Multiple DDOS protection interfaces merging on one TS server

Tags: linux, centos, ddos

The problem I have is I have 3 DDOS protection interfaces from a multi homed DDOS protection solution and teamspeak is refusing to return packets via the correct interface (aka the one that sent it with it's own IP mapping) causing errors unless I bind it to that interface but that then gets rid of the point of having the multi homed ddos protection it also needs to keep the real user IP address otherwise I can't effectively manage users as I can't ban or kick them or I ban/kick myself too.

[Here is the startup script to setup my current tunnels](http://pastebin.com/WACz67Z0)